# Calculate Time Difference in hh:mm

Tags: sql-server

I have this query but I'm not sure what function to use so I can get time difference in this "hh:mm" format. Can anybody help ?

```
SELECT        
EI.[FirstName]+' '+EI.[LastName] [EmployeeName], [Dpt].[FullName] [Department], [Desig].[FullName] [Designation],
FirstIN    = CAST(MIN([AttendanceTimeIn]) AS TIME), 
LastOUT    = CAST(MAX([AttendanceTimeOut]) AS TIME), 
HoursSpent = DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(MIN(AttendanceTimeIn) AS TIME), CAST(MAX(AttendanceTimeOut) AS TIME)),
CAST(COALESCE(AttendanceTimeIn, AttendanceTimeOut) AS DATE) [Date]

FROM [HRM].[tbl_Designation] [Desig], [HRM].[tbl_Department] [Dpt], [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [EI]

FULL OUTER JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAttendance] [Attendance] ON [Attendance].[EmpCode] = [EI].[ID] 

WHERE 

[Dpt].[ID] = [EI].[DeptCode] AND [Desig].[ID] = [EI].[DesignationCode]
AND
[EI].[RecordStatusCode] != '13'
AND 
CAST((GETDATE()-1) AS DATE) = CAST(ISNULL([AttendanceTimeIn], [AttendanceTimeOut]) AS Date)

GROUP BY
EI.[FirstName]+' '+EI.[LastName], [Dpt].[FullName], [Desig].[FullName], CAST(COALESCE(AttendanceTimeIn, AttendanceTimeOut) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Time isn't a good data type of durations.  Consider any operation that takes more than 24 hours to complete.  A common approach is to extract the duration in seconds, minutes or hours and format in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
declare @d1 datetime = '2018-01-11 23:40:18.010'
declare @d2 datetime = '2018-01-12 11:59:18.010'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(HOUR,@d2 - @d1)) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MINUTE,@d2 - @d1));
```

Comment: This won't work as you can see I have already used an aggregate function in my query to find Min and Max so can't user in another subquery.

Answer (score 1):

If to leave out your concept of using the time for the duration, you can use a query like below:

```
DECLARE @d1 DATETIME
DECLARE @d2 DATETIME

SELECT @d1 = GETDATE() - 1.465, @d2 = GETDATE()

SELECT
FirstIN    = @d1, 
LastOUT    = @d2, 
HoursSpent = CAST(DATEDIFF(HOUR, @d1, @d2) AS VARCHAR) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @d1, @d2) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is this query doing ?
Otherwise it won't make any difference

Comment: It calculates Time Difference in "hh:mm" between two dates as you asked

Answer (score 1):

Let's expand step by step:

```
declare
    @start datetime = getdate(),
    @end datetime = dateadd(second, getdate(), 5000)

-- datediff(hour, @start, @end) -> hour difference
-- dateadd(hour, @start, datediff(hour, @start, @end)) -> start + integer hour difference to get less-than-an-hour diff
-- datediff(minute, dateadd(hour, @start, datediff(hour, @start, @end)), @end) -> minute difference from there

select
    cast(datediff(hour, @start, @end) as varchar(2)) 
    + ':' 
    + cast(datediff(minute, dateadd(hour, @start, datediff(hour, @start, @end)), @end) as varchar(2)) as [hh:mm]
```